# Change the style of the controls that are exposed when a Datagrid is in Edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using a Library that has a class of type GanttChartDataGrid. For this question I am just concerned with the Datagrid. Currently, I used this code to acheive single click to edit in the grid. [Single Click to Edit Code](https://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing).

This works great, but the issue is, since my textboxes are in edit mode, they are exposed and you can see them. Making the datagrid look ugly here is a picture:

[image]

The cells under "Task" are all exposing their textboxes. In the next picture, I would like the cells to behave like how duration is. It shows it like a label within the grid and if it is not selected, once it becomes selected it displays the textbox.

[image]

I would like it to display the underlying textbox only when that row is selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my question.

I was databinding to Textboxes, I changed those to textblocks and now it works great.